# PHP: what is the convinient way to store variables in array?

Tags: php, arrays, store

I know it can be done like this

```
test['array'][0] = 'A';
test['array'][1] = 'B';
test['array'][2] = 'C';
test['array'][3] = 'D';
```

is there more simplier or better way to store variables in array than the example above?
^_^

Comment: do some google or have PHP manual, this is very basic can be get easily in manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way (works in all PHP versions)

```
$test['array'] = array('A','B','C','D');
```

In PHP 5.4 and later you can use JS style array declarations

```
$test['array'] = ['A','B','C','D'];
```

Comment: which is faster to execute in the 2 examples?

Comment: Both are language constructs so there should be no speed difference

Answer (score 3):

```
$test['array']=['A','B','C','D'];
```

Comment: +1 it's better than my solution :)

Comment: Is this even valid PHP? You should use square brackets (PHP 5.4+) instead of curly.

Comment: php 5.4+ is $test ['array'] = ['A', 'B'... I never seen it with { }

Comment: this is better but i like machavity answer because it works in all version still this is simplier

Answer (score 0):

```
test['array'][] = 'A';
test['array'][] = 'B';
test['array'][] = 'C';
test['array'][] = 'D';
```

or even simpler:

```
test[] = 'A';
test[] = 'B';
test[] = 'C';
test[] = 'D';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$test['array'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];`

`array_push($test['array'], 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');`